# Laravel Scribe Api Documentation - Skip a query string

Tags: laravel, scribe, api-doc

I want to be able to "skip" an argument from the documentation.

Use it like:

```
/*
* @queryParam some_param skip
* or
* @skipParam some_param
*/
```

It shouldn't matter from which strategy the param comes.

Is this achievable with default scribe?

In case you are wondering why I don't delete that parameter from the FormRequest - it's because I can't.